# Select2 returns TypeError: data is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get Select2 working with Rails. I have the API endpoint working but I get a `TypeError: data is undefined` message in my console, so the select fields aren't being populated.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $('#form_emails').select2({
    placeholder: 'User list',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/s/users',
      dataType: 'json',
      quietMillis: 250,
      data: function(term) {
        return { q: term };
      },
      results: function(data) {
        var results;
        results = [];
        $.each(data, function(idx, item) {
          results.push({
            'id': item.id,
            'text': item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name
          });
        });
        return { results: results };
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Any idea why I might be getting the aforementioned error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to use `processResults: function(data) {` instead of `results: function(data) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Select2 documentation the function where you can transform data from Ajax request is named `processResults`, not `results`.

See: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data

So the correct code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $('#form_emails').select2({
    placeholder: 'User list',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/s/users',
      dataType: 'json',
      quietMillis: 250,
      data: function(term) {
        return { q: term };
      },
      processResults: function(data) {
        var results;
        results = [];
        $.each(data, function(idx, item) {
          results.push({
            'id': item.id,
            'text': item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name
          });
        });
        return { results: results };
      }
    }
  });
});
```